# Declare variable without var keyword and logical OR

Tags: javascript

I get a strange behavior when declaring an object with the logical OR.

```
my_var = my_var || {}; // throws TypeError
```

If I add the `var` keyword

```
var my_var = my_var || {}; // returns empty object
```

Why is this? I can't seem to find an explanation. `my_var` is global scope, so why is `var` changing the behavior?

Comment: Could you provide a little bit more code? Is my_var defined earlier in the script at some point within the same scope? i'd assume so.

Comment: Yes, `my_var` should be declared early on in the execution. Specifically in another javascript source. I ran into this while testing in IE8. FireFox behaved as expected, but in IE8 I ran into some execution time issues. This mystery came up when I was trying to debug.

Comment: This all sounds like a good reason to actually explicitly check for undefined, to me.

Comment: @Tchalvak - True, I favor `if(typeof my_var == "undefined") my_var = {};`, but there are two schools of thought in this project. I've just never ran into this before today.

Comment: There is no need to check for undefined explicitly if you are aware what you are doing. If you want to assign to or read from the global object, you should always do so explicitly. In the browser the global object is always window, so write ``window.my_var = window.my_var || {};``. This will not fail, since undefined object members will not yield to a ReferenceError, but return undefined. If you are not inside the browser you can get a reference to the global object by doing ``(function(){ return this; })()``. This will not work with "use strict" though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first example tries to assign to a property on the global object named `my_var` by reading the value from an identifier called `my_var` (OR an empty object). However, the identifier `my_var` is not defined at that point, so it fails.

In the second example, due to how javascript variable hoisting works, the `my_var` variable is already declared, when you read from it by assign to it.

Also have a look at this example:

```
a = a; // fails, undeclared identifier
a = 0;
```

With var keyword it will work!

```
b = b; // succeeds allthough identifier undeclared?!
var b = 0;
```

This is because variable hoisting will turn it into this:

```
var b; // declaration of b hoisted to the top of scope
b = b;
b = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, the `var` defines the scope of `my_var`. This allows the value to be set properly. Here's a quick and dirty look at what's happening in both examples:

With example 1, the JS engine has to do the following:

1. Check the current scope to see if `my_var` exists.
2. Check the scope above (and the scope above that) until it finds `my_var`.
3. Create `my_var` in the global scope when it's not found.*

*Step 3 has not yet happened when you try to assign a value to `my_var`.

Example 2:

1. Is there a variable named `my_var` in the current scope? Yes, you just created it using the `var` keyword.
2. Assign its value.

Answer (score 1):

when defining a variable without `var`, you're directly accessing the `global object`. That means, your Javascript engine trys to lookup `my_var` on the global object (`window` if you're in a browser). Since that property does not exist yet, your JS engine will throw.

That happens on the *right side* of your statement, when your engine trys to read a variable with the name `my_var`. assigning like

```
my_var = {};
```

would work tho. But accessing an identifier without `var` will cause the browser to lookup the scopechain. Since the `variable object` for the global object is the global object itself, the lookup procedure will end up nowhere ( = exception ).

By putting the `var` keyword infront, your js engine knows at parsetime that it has to declare a new variable with that identifier name. It actually does declare that variable with an `undefined` value (that is called "hoisting"). That means, using `var` will prematurely create a property in the `current context` with that name. So if that code is not located in any function or eval context, it'll create the property `my_var` on the `window` object.

Answer (score 0):

In the 2nd situation, my var is undefined so the variable is assigned an empty object which is `{}`

Answer (score 0):

Although I cannot quote the specs, I assume that the initialization in a `var` statement is just syntactic sugar:

```
var my_var = my_var || {};
```

is equivalent to:

```
var my_var;
my_var = my_var || {};
```

In the first line, `my_var` is declared and implicitely set to the special value `undefined`.  Then, in the second line, `my_var` exists, `undefined` evaluates to `false` and no error is raised.

In your first example, however, `my_var` is unknown when the right hand side is evaluated, hence the error.

Comment: Right, but why does `var` change the declaration? Does `var` have a unique function to initialize `my_var`. Or another way to look at it, why does `var` change behavior of the logical OR?

Comment: `var` does not change the behavior of the OR! `var` declares a *local* variable and assigns the value `undefined` to it.  Declaring a variable without `var` creates a *global* variable.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you try to assign a variable that was not defined. Its the same as you would write :

```
my_var = a || {};
```

in the second case my_var is only undefined as you use the var keyword an create my_var in the actual scope. Undefined is converted to false and it will return the empty object.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, this *will* work:

```
a = my_var || {}; // 'a' is now an empty object
```

When you use the 'var' keyword you're literally giving the command "create a new variable and assign to it this value." If you don't use 'var' then you're implying that the variable already exists within the global scope somewhere.

In your example the JavaScript engine attempts to look up the current value of 'my_var', finds that it doesn't exist, cannot create it because you're currently attempting to assign a value to it, and fails.